# accessing columns after row being read csv file

Tags: python, csv, row, line

Ok I admit I made this way too complicated. I have uploaded a simple image. 
In a nutshell I can access the first line of each incident. (The numbers in the picture). I am able to manipulate and print them etc.

What I would like to do is to be able to manipulate select columns in the rows beneath the first line. So when I access row 1 (numbers) I would also be able to access "e,f,g" on row 2 and "z,z,z" in row 3 and so forth.

At the moment my code jumps straight from line 1 (numbers) to line 6 (numbers) then line 11 (numbers) etc.

[image]

Comment: please post your input as text. and also your desired output. how do you know a new incident starts at line 14? (i see 'Random Text' in column 'C'; but would that be the indicator of when a new incident starts?) please try do be as precise as possible...

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of data or code in your question, include the actual text from them.

Comment: The reason nobody wants to help you is your sentence structure is hard to understand. It's difficult to understand what you want to achieve. Can you add in your question the output you have and the expected output you want?

Comment: If you want random access to the `row` data, one thing you could do is read the entire file into a list-of-tuples (assuming it's not too large).

Comment: Thanks folks. I have updated the pictures Input Csv file and desired outcome. I can read the first line of each incident and write it. i.e as far as investigating officer. Its when the information (Injured party, suspect) is on a different row that im having difficulty

Comment: please **do not post pictures** of the `csv` data. post the data **as text**  here. so if there is something written in column 'D' a new incident starts? (people here need samples of your data to test the code they propose. nobody is going to type any data from your pictures...)

Comment: sorry guys I cant upload the real file due to legal and data protection. Ive been trying to rejig it so that i could post, but its just not working out. Ill have to come back to it tomorrow as my brain is fried. Thanks for all the help thus far and sorry about not having it right first time.

Comment: Ive fixed the code and uploaded some csv text. The first line of each incident saves to a text file. Its the blue writing im trying to add to it.